# Why is react-markdown outputting code blocks instead of HTM:

Tags: reactjs, markdown, jsx

I'm trying to convert Markdown to HTML using react-markdown. My code is pretty straightforward:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';

const markdown = `
        # Header 1
        ## Header 2
        _ italic _
        ** bold **
        <b> bold Html </b>
    `;
    return (
        <div className='sidebar-right'>
            <div className='main-bar'> 
                <ReactMarkdown source={markdown} />        
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

My problem is that the output in the browser is a code block, and not the HTML I expected. I realise that my markdown content is wrapped in backticks, which designates it as code in markdown, but that's what the  plugin example says I should do. Any suggestions as to how I can get this to work would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks and regards,
Dan.

Comment: The backticks simply mark it as a string literal, if you have just a single pair it should not become part of the string

Answer (score 1):

Your markdown source is this:

```
        # Header 1
        ## Header 2
        _ italic _
        ** bold **
        <b> bold Html </b>
```

Whereas it should be this:

```
# Header 1
## Header 2
_ italic _
** bold **
<b> bold Html </b>
```

In Markdown, indented lines (in most contexts) indicate code blocks.

You need to declare it like this:

```js
    const markdown = `# Header 1
## Header 2
_ italic _
** bold **
<b> bold Html </b>`;
```

This is because template literals do not automatically trim indentation.

Alternatively, strip the indentation programmatically, something like this:

```js
const stripIndent = ([str]) => {
    try {
        const lines = str.split("\n")

        const firstContentfulLine = lines[0].trim() ? lines[0] : lines[1]

        const indent = firstContentfulLine.match(/^\s*/)[0].length

        const result = lines
            .map(l => l.slice(indent))
            .join("\n")
            .trim()

        return result
    } catch (_e) {
        return str
    }
}

const markdown = stripIndent`
    # Header 1
    ## Header 2
    _ italic _
    ** bold **
    <b> bold Html </b>
`
```

Comment: Hi Lionel, Yes! That's exactly the problem. I changed the indentation as you suggested and it now works perfectly. Thank you for your very detailed explanation. Regards, Dan.

Answer (score 0):

If you read documentation you know need to add `escapeHtml={false}`

```
<ReactMarkdown
  source={markdown}
  escapeHtml={false}
/>
```

Comment: I followed the example given in the plugin, and they do not use 'escapeHtml'. I tried it as you suggested and it doesn't make any difference. The correct solution is provide by the previous answer. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with some nicely formatted JSON containing Markdown templates that were therefore indented, and I wanted to keep the JSON formatting. Lionel's solution is on the right lines, but you don't need all the code as String.prototype.trim() will trim whitespace from both ends of a string, which means you don't need to work out what the indent is. I simplified it as follows:

```
const stripIndent = (str) => {
  try {
    return str.split("\n").map(l => l.trim()).join('\n')
  } catch {
    return str
  }
}
```

All this code does is split the template literal into arrays of lines, trims the lines and joins them back up again.